# how to access keys and values from list of map dictionary using Terraform for loop

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I tried this so much but could not figure out how to do this. I have a following YAML file below.

```
---
project_team_mapping:
- Terraform-Project-1:                      ## this is project name
    - team_name: example-team-1
      roles:
        - GROUP_READ_ONLY
        - GROUP_DATA_ACCESS_READ_WRITE
    - team_name: example-team-2
      roles:
        - GROUP_READ_ONLY
        - GROUP_DATA_ACCESS_READ_WRITE
- Terraform-Project-2:                       ## this is 2nd project name
    - team_name: example-team-3
      roles:
        - GROUP_READ_ONLY
        - GROUP_DATA_ACCESS_READ_WRITE
    - team_name: example-team-4
      roles:
        - GROUP_READ_ONLY
        - GROUP_DATA_ACCESS_READ_WRITE
```

I'm using some TF module to decode the YAML files and here is the module and the YAML decoded output JSON.

```
module "yaml_json_multidecoder" {
  source  = "levmel/yaml_json/multidecoder"
  version = "0.2.1"
  filepaths = ["./examples/*.yaml"]
}

output "project_team_mapping" {
  value = module.yaml_json_multidecoder.files.project.project_team_mapping
}
```

below is the output when using above decoder module.

```
project_team_mapping = [
  {
    "Terraform-Project-1" = [
      {
        "roles" = [
          "GROUP_READ_ONLY",
          "GROUP_DATA_ACCESS_READ_WRITE",
        ]
        "team_name" = "dx-example-team-3"
      },
      {
        "roles" = [
          "GROUP_READ_ONLY",
          "GROUP_DATA_ACCESS_READ_WRITE",
        ]
        "team_name" = "dx-example-team-4"
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

i would like to create resources using Terraform for/for_each function and dynamic functions for a particular resource block below, i'm strugging not able to understand the outcome.

Below is the resource block going to use

```
resource "mongodbatlas_project" "test" {
  name   = "project-name"
  org_id = "<ORG_ID>"
  project_owner_id = "<OWNER_ACCOUNT_ID>"

 # want to use dynamic function here to create multiple teams
  teams {
    team_id    = "5e0fa8c99ccf641c722fe645"
    role_names = ["GROUP_OWNER"]

  }

}
```

can someone help please?

```
resource "mongodbatlas_project" "test" {
  name   = "project-name"
  org_id = "<ORG_ID>"
  project_owner_id = "<OWNER_ACCOUNT_ID>"

 # want to use dynamic function here to create multiple teams
  teams {
    team_id    = "5e0fa8c99ccf641c722fe645"
    role_names = ["GROUP_OWNER"]

  }

}
```

**I might use wrong YAML structuring, please suggest good structure to fit my needs. i can change the YAML.**

above question i'm using team_name in YAML but the resource block takes team_id. i'm planning to use data function to get ID but if you happen to have a easy solution please suggest

Comment: Please provide more code, showing how do you read the yaml file, and how do you try to use it. Also provide errors that you are getting.

Comment: Thanks. Just have a look at @dlapcenko answer. I think its good.

Answer (score 1):

Many unknowns you have left. But a best guess would be the example below.
Assuming you have decoded yaml into a `local.decodedyaml`. Also you possibly would need `team_id` instead of `team_name`, maybe you can load them via data source, or will have to retrieve and add to yaml manually.

```
resource "mongodbatlas_project" "test" {
  for_each = local.decodedyaml.project_team_mapping

  name   = each.key
  org_id = "<ORG_ID>"
  project_owner_id = "<OWNER_ACCOUNT_ID>"

  dynamic "teams" {
    for_each = {
      for team in each.value: team.team_name => team.roles
    }

    content {
      team_id = each.key
      role_names = each.value
    }
  }
}
```

This will work if you change the data design to "unwrap" the initial lists:
Instead of

```
project_team_mapping:
- Terraform-Project Name-1:                      ## this is project name
    - team_name: example-team-1
      roles:
        - GROUP_READ_ONLY
        - GROUP_DATA_ACCESS_READ_WRITE
    ...
- Terraform-Project Name-2:                       ## this is 2nd project name
    - team_name: example-team-3
      roles:
        - GROUP_READ_ONLY
        - GROUP_DATA_ACCESS_READ_WRITE
    ...
```

Use

```
project_team_mapping:
  Terraform-Project Name-1:                      ## this is project name
    - team_name: example-team-1
      roles:
        - GROUP_READ_ONLY
        - GROUP_DATA_ACCESS_READ_WRITE
    ...
  Terraform-Project Name-2:                       ## this is 2nd project name
    - team_name: example-team-3
      roles:
        - GROUP_READ_ONLY
        - GROUP_DATA_ACCESS_READ_WRITE
    ...
```

This eases the data structure and greatly eases the hcl parsing.

Lastly, I am not sure yaml keys with spaces are a risk-free endevour.

Comment: `local.decodedyaml.project_team_mapping` is a list of maps, which will not work with `for_each`. You may need to revise the answer to account for that.

Comment: you are right! my brain skipped this awkward moment of the structure design. What could be the benefit to having a list of maps with one key there..?

Comment: @dlapcenko i might be uisng wrong structure i dont know how to design it, but inorder to achive my use case what is the best way to structure this ? any suggestions please. thanks